# Selecting latest file from a folder and copy it to another file using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell scripts and need some help.

We have a folder `\Output`. It will have the files in following format :

```
abc_1.dat
abc_2.dat
xyz_1.dat
abc_3.dat
pqr_2.dat
......
```

Now I want to find the latest file starting with "abc" (e.g., abc_3.dat) and copy the data to abc.dat. Similarly for xyz and pqr. These files will keep on being added.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find your list of unique prefixes:

```
$prefixes = Get-ChildItem \Output | 
    Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Name.Substring(0, 3) } |
    Select-Object -Unique
```

Then, for each prefix, find the latest/highest number and copy it to the preferred file:

```
$latest = $prefixes | 
    Foreach-Object { 
        Join-Path \Output "$_*" |
        Get-ChildItem |
        Add-Member NoteProperty -Name ID -Value { [int] ($_.BaseName -split '_')[1] } -PassThru |
        Sort-Object ID -Descending |
        Select-Object -First |
        Copy-Item -Destination \Output\$_.dat
    }
```

Comment: Hi Splattered bits , thanks for the reply. Can I just copy these two commands in script as is and run ?

Comment: You should be able to.  Make sure you test it, of course.  I make no guarantees that what I wrote will work, but it should get you started.  I would add a -WhatIf parameter to that last Copy-Item until you're sure things work.

Comment: Hi Splattered bits, thanks . I'll try it and get back you soon. appreciate your help.